# How to use URL Scheme with Apple Clips

Tags: ios, instagram, url-scheme

Is it possible to use Instagram URL App Scheme with the ios app clips?

I would like to push stickers into the user's Instagram Story. That's possible with a native App therefore I'm interested in whether it works with app clips as well.

Comment: did you resolve it

Comment: Unfortunately not